# git diff tries to compare files which don't exist

Tags: git, diff

When I do `git diff` it tries to launch my diff tool with files which do not exist. I assume it's getting the last version of the changed `.gitignore` file and copying it to a temporary file. So I see it launching:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\diff.exe" .gitignore C:/temp/D4Sgyb_.gitignore 55f1.... 100644 .gitignore 000.... 100644
```

But the diff tool complains, rightly so, that `C:/temp/D4Sgyb_.gitignore` does not exist. Is it not being created or deleted too soon?

Comment: Normally `git diff` does its own internal diff, but if you *tell* it to use some other program, it invokes this "external" diff with seven arguments: *path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode*. This appears to be the launching of an external diff. See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html#_git_diffs

Comment: But it's apparently failing to create the temp file it passes to the external tool.

Comment: Interesting. The docs mention (and the code is written to do this) that Git will delete the temp file as soon as the external program finishes, i.e., exits and the process is collected by Git. I don't "do" Windows but perhaps something is doing the equivalent of a Unix/Linux "double fork"? Or it's just a bug in Windows Git, failing to notice that it was never able to create the temp file. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Inside git repo every file is compressed. So if you want to compare file than is not in your working directory, git need to unpack this file to temporary directory.

Maybe your C:/temp dir is not exists or you do not have full access to it (or some antivirus remove this file). I believe that "C:/temp" is bad path for modern Windows. Check your PATH env.

Comment: It's actually not `c:\temp` but my user's `%temp%` folder. I just anonymized the data. I do indeed have rights to right to the folder.

Comment: Do you use internal diff utils or some other app and also "anonymized" it?

Comment: I did originally, but I switched back to the git diff tool to see if that helped. The example above is indeed the path to the diff.exe I am using.